# prerequisites for installing cloudbees plug-in

Tags: eclipse-plugin, cloudbees

m trying to install cloudbees plugin in my eclipse juno but its giving me error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: CloudBees Eclipse Toolkit SVN Support (**SUBCLIPSE MUST BE INSTALLED!!**) (Optional) 1.1.0.201210091648 (com.cloudbees.eclipse.dev.scm.subclipse.feature.group 1.1.0.201210091648)
  Missing requirement: CloudBees Scm Subclipse 1.1.0.201210091648 (com.cloudbees.eclipse.dev.scm.subclipse 1.1.0.201210091648) requires 'bundle org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core [1.6.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CloudBees Eclipse Toolkit SVN Support (**SUBCLIPSE MUST BE INSTALLED!!**) (Optional) 1.1.0.201210091648 (com.cloudbees.eclipse.dev.scm.subclipse.feature.group 1.1.0.201210091648)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Subclipse.

If you are using Subversion for your version control system, you might be using either Subclipse or Subversive in Eclipse. Depending on which one you use, you should install the corresponding CloudBees toolkit adapter. You do not need the other one, and if you are using Git (or something else) you do not need either.